# How to find quicly a duplicated bone name

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm rigging the tail of the bird Piero training course of the CG Cookie and I made again and again the `episode 29 : piero rigging spine`. I created a new bone and I renamed it "`MCH_mindsEye`",as indicated by the tutorial,but that name has been converted immediately to "`MCH_mindsEye.001`",so probably already exists a bone with the first/same name. I tried to look where it could be but I didn't find it. What can I do ? I have also unhide all the bones that I had previously hidden,but that doesn't help.

[image: bone name converted to .001]

Comment: On the upper right of your screen capture you can see a search text box, in the outliner panel. Type "MCH_mindsEye" in it.

Comment: I found it : https://postimg.org/image/7r8pv8hnf/ ; but now how can I remove it ? I can't see where it is on the 3d View

Comment: Select it using RMB in the outliner (in edit mode for your armature) and choose select. Then delete it normally in the 3D view

Comment: If you don't see it, that can be because it is accidentally hidden. Try "alt+h" if the previous steps do not work

Comment: no man,don't work. I tried to unhide it,but I can't see where it is on the 3d view : ---> https://postimg.org/image/cfv8kp6o5/

Comment: try doing that in edit mode, your last image is in pose mode

Comment: I deleted the bone "MCH_mindsEye.001" and also "MCH_mindsEye" has gone. But I couldn't see where it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlite it in the list as suggested, look in the 3D window for the gismo arrows.  That's where it should be, even when you cannot see it.  Sometimes these things appear as just a highlited dot in the 3D screen.

Good luck - it's a perplexing problem that one!

Comment: It happened again. This time I tried to create the bone "MCH_eyeINT.R",but it is converted to "MCH_eyeINT.R.001". I found "MCH_eyeINT.R" on the outliner,but I can't see it on the 3d View. Can you check by yourself ?---> https://postimg.org/image/o5fwkqhgl/

Comment: This happens to me a lot so I end up expanding the text slot where the .001 name is and find my original name, select it.  The bone I've created then takes on that name.  So far nothing untoward has happened each time I do this.   This occurs when I create a new material channel also, and frequently.  Again I simply force it to take the original name from the expanded list.  I'll have a play to refresh my memory as to the fine detail and get back to you...

Comment: I've revisited the problem but apart from the .001 name being added to the list, cannot get anything to disappear.  Hope you've got on top of it by now.

Comment: yes I found where I wrong. I'd hidden the first copies of the bones using the "bone layer management" addon by alfonso annarumma.